# Why i can't run flutter after i upgrade android studio v.2020.3.1

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio

[image]

Hi, i got the trouble when after upgrade android studio v.2020.3.1 in flutter. i had upgrade my flutter. but, it can't resolved this. Can you tell me how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried the thing the error message suggests you try?

Comment: yes. but, i can't find where a place of bundle java in flutter mac os @Koenigsberg. it make me small hurt

Comment: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.              
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @10cd1b7a -> this error from flutter -Koenigsberg

Comment: "Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.              
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module 10cd1b7a" - @Koenigsberg